# Battery 100% still charging

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery

I have a Acer AspireV3-772G running Windowws 8.1. My battery indicator shows 100% available ( plugged in,charging) status. I calibrated the battery but no difference. Also I have bought a new battery, but is still battery indicator shows 100% available ( plugged in,charging) status Battery is still in good condition and it still holds a 2-3 hours talk time.

What should I do to fix this problem or is it safe to continue using with AC power. Charging indicator bulb is turned on all the time so I feel that the laptop tries to overcharge the battery. Will it reduce the battery life?

Just for now I removed the battery from the laptop as a precaution. But I need a solution to the problem. It doesn't recognize when it's fully charged.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with that indication. Ignore it.
No, there will be no damage to your battery, its safe to use AC power.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with my old laptop, the issue was in the charger itself which did not give enough power required by the system.

Comment: Possibly related, but it's unlikely then that the machine would display "100% charged, plugged in, charging". If your power brick (the "charger" is actually in the laptop; all the power brick does is convert AC to voltage-regulated DC) is not providing sufficient power then the battery isn't going to reach 100% charge.

Answer (score 0):

Different laptops have different uses of their "battery" light. Many of them will blink the battery LED during charging, but leave it on steady after the battery is fully charged. Windows likewise - the status tray indicator on my laptops always says "100% and charging". They've never overcharged their batteries.

Answer (score 0):

Every laptop pack/module/battery has a built in controller, which monitors the level of charge in the battery.  If the cell is full, it will disconnect the battery from power.

Even the OS, and the charging indicator itself, indicate that the battery is charging.  However, the controller inside the battery pack already cut the power when battery cell reached full charge.

I do not think there a problem here.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Not all charging setups are created equal just consider the technology involved in charging a MacBook compared to your average Windows laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a Toshiba Satellite C855D running Windows 10. The battery meter in Windows showed "Fully Charged 100%" but my laptop's battery light showed that it was still charging. After about 10 minutes of it like this I saw the laptop's battery indicator light show fully charged. I think that the problem could be caused by a slow charger, but even then it just took a little longer for the battery pack to register as charged. The OS has its own algorithm for determining battery level, and therefore I would trust the laptop's battery indicator light since it shows charged once that battery pack itself cuts the power. I think that there is no problem here. Hope this helps.